# How to prevent particular symbols appear in string alternately

Tags: regex

I want to construct a regex rule for email username and came up with `/^[0-9a-z](?:_?[a-z0-9]+\.?)*$/i`. And username `p_r_i_k._c` meets this requirement. How to add rule to prevent `_` and `.` appearing one after another?

Comment: Which of the following must the email not contain? `_.`, `._`, `..`, `__`?

Comment: `^\w*_?(?!\.)$`

I think what you want is a Negative Lookahead.  This ensures an underscore is not followed by a period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a anchored negative look-ahead:

```
^(?!.*[._]{2})<your regex>
```

ie

```
/^(?!.*[._]{2})[0-9a-z](?:_?[a-z0-9]+\.?)*$/i
```

It's not clear from your question which of `_.`, `._`, `..`, `__` must be prevented. This answer prevents all of them. To prevent just some, alte `[._]{2}` to for example `\._` to only prevent `\._`

Answer (score 0):

In the pattern you tried the `._` can match due to the repetition of the group `(?:_?[a-z0-9]+\.?)*` where the `.` at the end can meet the `_` at the start again.

If there can not be a dot or underscore at the end and the pattern can only start with a single char:

```
^[0-9a-z](?:[_.][a-z0-9]+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/joqh2f/1)

If it can end on a dot or underscore, you can add an optional character class at the end:

```
^[0-9a-z](?:[_.][a-z0-9]+)*[_.]?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NXctWo/1)